# geom_text in ggplot2 are not shown

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've created a plot like this:

[image]

by using the `mkplot()` function defined here:

```
mkplot <- function(m, title, subtitle = "", swap.axis = FALSE) {
    if (swap.axis) {
      ggplot(data = m, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value, label = vtext)) +
        xlab("") + ylab("") +
        geom_tile() +
        geom_text(aes(color = value > 0.6*max(m$value))) +
        scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c("black", "white")) + #geom_text() +
        scale_fill_gradient(low="beige", high="brown4") +
        # Sample code for subtitles: ggtitle(bquote(atop("Age distribution", atop(italic(.(subtitle)), ""))))
        ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(title), atop(italic(.(subtitle)), "")))) +
        theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
              axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
              plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
              panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
              legend.key.size = unit(0.02, "npc"),
              legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
              legend.title = element_text(size = 16))
    } else {
      ggplot(data = m, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = value, label = vtext)) +
        xlab("") + ylab("") +
        geom_tile() +
        geom_text(aes(color = value > 0.6*max(m$value))) +
        scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c("black", "white")) + #geom_text() +
        scale_fill_gradient(low="beige", high="brown4") +
        # Sample code for subtitles: ggtitle(bquote(atop("Age distribution", atop(italic(.(subtitle)), ""))))
        ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(title), atop(italic(.(subtitle)), "")))) +
        theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
              axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
              plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
              panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
              legend.key.size = unit(0.02, "npc"),
              legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
              legend.title = element_text(size = 16))  
    }

}
```

This function accepts a matrix where the `vtext` column contains the labels to show at the coordinates defined by the columns `Var1` and `Var2` and returns a plot object. However, when I call the function with the following dataset, the text is not shown:

[image]

```
m <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("FE", "AG", 
"NO", "SPH", "SEP", "H/I", "CMP"), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L
), .Label = c("FE", "AG", "NO", "SPH", "SEP", "H/I", "CMP"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(NA, 4.02149347178743, 1.91571478755385, 1.97927899702546, 
    2.02603899244707, 2.16281145091151, 1.59833957894136, 3.17739392983327, 
    NA, 1.64295952963793, 1.61938283892958, 2.01876401368226, 
    2.27583054552681, 1.92162040673626, 1.50343303384468, 1.5912590928444, 
    NA, 1.47906635805171, 1.26558011163096, 1.44998903804508, 
    1.37770174407686, 1.93309549042729, 1.74420096205238, 1.90134281743486, 
    NA, 1.27695246179966, 1.54810486167689, 1.56842318564524, 
    2.81544501207105, 1.94591127739177, 1.82503474449433, 1.66343561213693, 
    NA, 4.37746171596392, 2.85325226018081, 2.08623825385336, 
    2.0233480547976, 1.75090243733866, 1.89848629646063, 2.63683490455119, 
    NA, 2.68804806948658, 1.75131933951687, 1.47327632282202, 
    1.84345393451446, 1.74482341831917, 2.57428820233227, 3.01688030649311, 
    NA), vtext = c(NA, "4.0", "1.9", "2.0", "2.0", "2.2", "1.6", 
    "3.2", NA, "1.6", "1.6", "2.0", "2.3", "1.9", "1.5", "1.6", 
    NA, "1.5", "1.3", "1.4", "1.4", "1.9", "1.7", "1.9", NA, 
    "1.3", "1.5", "1.6", "2.8", "1.9", "1.8", "1.7", NA, "4.4", 
    "2.9", "2.1", "2.0", "1.8", "1.9", "2.6", NA, "2.7", "1.8", 
    "1.5", "1.8", "1.7", "2.6", "3.0", NA)), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Var2", "value", "vtext"), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")

p <- mkplot(ma, "All breeds", "HIGH/LOW ratio")

plot(p)
```

What I'm missing here? I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `na.rm = TRUE` argument in `max` function. Text line should look like this:

```
geom_text(aes(color = value > 0.6 * max(m$value, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

**PS.:**

You can simplify your function like this:

```
mkplot <- function(m, title = NULL, subtitle = NULL, swap.axis = FALSE) {
    library(ggplot2)
    p <- ggplot(m, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value, label = vtext)) +
        labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
        geom_tile() +
        geom_text(aes(color = value > 0.6 * max(m$value, na.rm = TRUE))) +
        scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c("black", "white")) +
        scale_fill_gradient(low="beige", high="brown4") +
        ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(title), atop(italic(.(subtitle)), "")))) +
        theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 12), 
              axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
              plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
              panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
              legend.key.size = unit(0.02, "npc"),
              legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
              legend.title = element_text(size = 16))
    if (swap.axis) {
        p <- p + coord_flip()
    }
    return(p)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The pblm comes from you `colour` definition, which return an error :

```
0.6*max(m$value)
[1] NA
```

Try with :

```
ggplot(data = m, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value, label = vtext)) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(color = value > 0.6*max(m$value, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

[image]

```
p <- mkplot(m, "All breeds", "HIGH/LOW ratio")
plot(p)
```

[image]

By the way, ggplots are objects on which you can add any new function call. As your code has a lot of duplication, I would suggest your function to be more like :

```
mkplot <- function(m, title, subtitle = "", swap.axis = FALSE) {
  if (swap.axis) {
    call < - ggplot(data = m, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value, label = vtext)) 
  } else {
    call <- ggplot(data = m, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = value, label = vtext))  
  }
  call +
    xlab("") + ylab("") +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(aes(color = value > 0.6*max(m$value, na.rm = TRUE))) +
    scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c("black", "white")) + #geom_text() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="beige", high="brown4") +
    # Sample code for subtitles: ggtitle(bquote(atop("Age distribution", atop(italic(.(subtitle)), ""))))
    ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(title), atop(italic(.(subtitle)), "")))) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          legend.key.size = unit(0.02, "npc"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 16)) 
}
```

Also, there's a `coord_flip` function in {ggplot2} that does this job:

```
mkplot <- function(m, title, subtitle = "", swap.axis = FALSE) {
  ggcall <- ggplot(data = m, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value, label = vtext)) +
    xlab("") + ylab("") +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(aes(color = value > 0.6*max(m$value, na.rm = TRUE))) +
    scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c("black", "white")) + #geom_text() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="beige", high="brown4") +
    # Sample code for subtitles: ggtitle(bquote(atop("Age distribution", atop(italic(.(subtitle)), ""))))
    ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(title), atop(italic(.(subtitle)), "")))) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          legend.key.size = unit(0.02, "npc"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 16)) 
  if (swap.axis) {
    ggcall + coord_flip()
  } else {
    ggcall 
  }
}

p <- mkplot(m, "All breeds", "HIGH/LOW ratio")
plot(p)
```

[image]

```
pswap <- mkplot(m, "All breeds", "HIGH/LOW ratio", swap.axis = TRUE)
plot(pswap)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @ColinFAY That works! I've accepted the other answer because it came first, but Thank you for posting a plot with the result of the solution.